# maximum value for many rows

Tags: sql, db2-400

I am looking to get the max value, but when I have several rows.
something similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852274/select-maximum-row-value-by-group), but for DB2:

This is what i'd like to accomplish:
I have a table with orders a client made and would like to select the last order according to the highest order date.

```
client  order date    ord number
111     2013-01-01    asdf      |
222     2013-01-05    kjhg      |
111     2013-02-02    uiop      |
222     2013-02-06    fghj      |
```

result

```
client  order date
111     2013-02-02
222     2013-02-06
```

I wish I was able to post an image, but it wont allow me...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want a `group by`?

```
select client, max(OrderDate) as OrderDate
from orders o
group by client;
```

If you want the complete row, there are several ways.  One way is with `row_number()`:

```
select o.*
from (select o.*, row_number() over (partition by client order by orderdate desc) as seqnum
      from orders o
     ) o
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 2nd answer is a bit complicated for me, not sure I can test it. For the 1st one, it works only if I have 1 table. When linking 2 or more tables with sometime duplicated in first or 2nd column (ex, additional tables has 2 or more lines for each order), this solution doesn't work.

Comment: @OGERWOLF . . . Your question only mentions one table.  If you have additional tables, you should ask another question.

Comment: Actually, I have 3-4 tables...depends on the query. It is just that I need to have those linked in order to have my result However, I do not necessarily have them in the select. Should I create a new question? Thanks

Comment: @OGERWOLF . . . This question is:  "I have a table with orders a client made and would like to select the last order according to the highest order date.".  If you have another question, then ask another question.