# R: How to combine rows of a data frame with the same id and take the newest non-NA value?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Example data frame

```
date       name     speed  acceleration
1/1/17     bob      5      NA
1/1/15     george   5      NA
1/1/15     bob      NA     4
1/1/17     bob      4      NA
```

I want to condense all rows with the same name into one row and keep the newest non-na value for the speed and acceleration column.

Desired output

```
date       name     speed  acceleration
1/1/17     bob      5      4
1/1/15     george   5      NA
```

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237399/how-to-select-the-rows-with-maximum-values-in-each-group-with-dplyr) for how to select the maximum value (max works with dates).

Comment: @Malo: Here it's not the max but the newest, you don't take the max speed but the latest speed w.r.t. date column. So i don't think your link is relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

input = read.table(text = 
 "date       name     speed  acceleration
  1/1/17     bob      5      NA
  1/1/15     george   5      NA
  1/1/15     bob      NA     4
  1/1/17     bob      4      NA",
  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

output <- input %>%
  mutate(date = mdy(date)) %>% # or maybe dmy, depending on your date format
  group_by(name) %>%
  arrange(desc(date)) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(na.omit(.)[1]))

output
# # A tibble: 2 × 4
#     name       date speed acceleration
#    <chr>     <date> <int>        <int>
# 1    bob 2017-01-01     5            4
# 2 george 2015-01-01     5           NA
```

Comment: It's a little simpler to just use `na.omit`.

Comment: Something like `dat %>% ... summarize_all(function(x) na.omit(x)[1] )` would simplify this too applying the same function to all columns.

Comment: or use `funs`: `summarise_all(funs(na.omit(.)[1]))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(input)`), `order` the 'date' after converting to `Date` class, grouped by 'name', loop through the columns and get the first non-NA element

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
setDT(input)[order(-mdy(date)), lapply(.SD, function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1]), name]
#     name   date speed acceleration
#1:    bob 1/1/17     5            4
#2: george 1/1/15     5           NA
```