# Summarize with mathematical conditions in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements, summarize

Building on this question: [Summarize with conditions in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528862/summarize-with-conditions-in-dplyr)
I would like to use `dplyr` to summarize a column based on a mathematical condition (not string matching as in the linked post). I need to find the maximum `measurement` when the ratio of `measurement`/`time` is the highest, while creating a new column `ratio`. I'd also like to carry through the entire row, which I'm unsure how to do with `dplyr`'s `summarize` function.

---

**Example Data Frame**

```
print(df)

   sample     type time measurement
1       a bacteria   24     0.57561
2       a bacteria   44     1.67236
3       a bacteria   67     4.17100
4       a bacteria   88    11.51661
5       b bacteria   24     0.53269
6       b bacteria   44     1.24942
7       b bacteria   67     5.72147
8       b bacteria   88    11.04017
9       c bacteria    0     0.00000
10      c bacteria   24     0.47418
11      c bacteria   39     1.06286
12      c bacteria   64     3.59649
13      c bacteria   78     7.05190
14      c bacteria  108     7.27060
```

---

**Desired Output**

```
  sample     type time measurement      ratio
1      a bacteria   88    11.51661 0.13087057
2      b bacteria   88    11.04017 0.12545648
3      c bacteria   78     7.05190 0.09040897
```

---

**Failed Attempt**

This only returns the two columns as defined by the `group_by` and `summarize` function, would like to have the entire row information carry through:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(sample) %>%
    summarize(ratio = max(measurement/time, na.rm = TRUE))

  sample  ratio
  <fct>   <dbl>
1 a      0.131 
2 b      0.125 
3 c      0.0904
```

---

**Reproducible Data**

```
structure(list(sample = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), 
    type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "bacteria", class = "factor"), 
    time = c(24, 44, 67, 88, 24, 44, 67, 88, 0, 24, 39, 64, 78, 
    108), measurement = c(0.57561, 1.67236, 4.171, 11.51661, 
    0.53269, 1.24942, 5.72147, 11.04017, 0, 0.47418, 1.06286, 
    3.59649, 7.0519, 7.2706)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select the rows with maximum values in each group with dplyr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237399/how-to-select-the-rows-with-maximum-values-in-each-group-with-dplyr)

Comment: I don't think it does exactly. It's similar but I have a compounded conditional where the answer there just looks to find the maximum value.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly, since in your example you're taking the maximum of the ratio. Is that not the condition you want?

Comment: It's very similar but I needed to involve the use of multiple columns (not just a max of a single value in a column), minor difference. I can see why it would be marked a duplicate. However, I'm an experienced SO/Googler could not find the answer so others may struggle too. I provided a link that will be helpful for future SO users in case they follow my search patterns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df %>%
  mutate(ratio = measurement/time) %>%
  group_by(sample) %>%
  filter(ratio == max(ratio, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick.

```
df %>%
   group_by(sample) %>%
   mutate(ratio = measurement/time) %>%
   filter(ratio == max(ratio))
```

Comment: Why are you calling `summarise`? Why not just drop the column you don't want to keep?

Comment: Well pointed. In fact there's no need to drop columns or summarise anything. By construction there'll be only a single row per sample.

Comment: This drops my "c" sample.

Comment: Do you have any missing data? If so, pass `max()` the `na.rm = TRUE` argument

Answer (score 2):

An option would be to `filter` 'measurement' based on the `max` position of measurement/time and use that to compare (`==`) with the 'measurement' values after grouping by 'sample'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(sample) %>% 
   mutate(ratio = measurement/time) %>%
   filter(measurement == measurement[which.max(ratio)])
```