# R mutate a dataframe based on max in a column using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, max

I want to use ddply or group_by to mutate an existing dataframe based on the values in one of the columns in the dataframe.

I have a dataframe with 3 columns. I want to identify the ROI *within* each ID and Condition that has the maximum value in df$Value. So for the following df, ROI 3 would be called Max for ID 1+Match condition, ROI 4 would be Max for ID 1+NoMatch Condition and so on.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame("ID"=sort(rep_len(1:2, 12)), "ROI"=rep_len(1:6, 12), "Condition"=rep_len(c(rep_len("Match", 3), rep_len("NoMatch", 3)), 12), "Value"=runif(12), MaxROI="None")
```

I tried using some combinations of ddply and group_by. For instance:

```
ddply(df, c("ID", "Condition"), mutate, MaxROI[which.max(Value)]="Max")

#generates an error
#Error: unexpected '=' in "ddply(df, c("ID", "Condition"), mutate, MaxROI[which.max(Value)]="
```

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237399/how-to-select-the-rows-with-maximum-values-in-each-group-with-dplyr), but I don't want to filter the dataframe to keep the rows with max values, but mutate the existing df.

Thank you,

Mrinmayi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`.  After grouping by 'ID', 'Condition', create the column 'Max' by comparing the 'Value' with `max` of 'Value' in `case_when` to create the "Max" string where there is a max 'Value' or else by default it is NA

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(ID, Condition) %>% 
   dplyr::mutate(Max =case_when(Value == max(Value) ~ "Max"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response!

Ideally, I would like to label an ROI as max, instead of importing the actual Value. I could do that with an additional step of:

` df[df$value==df$Max, "MaxROI" <- "Max" `
unless there is a better way.

Also, is there an easy way to handle cases that may have multiple ROIs that have the same Value, and therefore don't have a max?

Comment: Works perfectly for cases where there is a max! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Mrinmayi thanks.  If it works, please consider to accept solution by clicking on the tick mark. It would also improve your reputation